# "Not a vso image, so not writing build commands" during dev ops deploy : $func azure functionapp publish. python

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-functions

What could cause the fact that pip install does nothing during publish?
In stead I get the message `Not a vso image, so not writing build commands`

Any ideas?

```
❯ func azure functionapp publish <function> --python
Getting site publishing info...
Creating archive for current directory...
Performing remote build for functions project.
Deleting the old .python_packages directory
Uploading 58.18 MB [##############################################################################]
Remote build in progress, please wait...
Updating submodules.
Preparing deployment for commit id 'b731a092-c'.
PreDeployment: context.CleanOutputPath False
PreDeployment: context.OutputPath /home/site/wwwroot
Repository path is /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
Running oryx build...
Command: oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /tmp/build/expressbuild --platform python --platform-version 3.8 -i /tmp/8da4bb5df31e64ce -p packagedir=.python_packages/lib/site-packages
Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues

Oryx Version: 0.2.20220308.4, Commit: c92fa6a2d6fc14dc9646df80e2bb2e393a5cdc258, ReleaseTagName: 20220308.4

Build Operation ID: |3oThCwt0g+I=.d2a2da5e0_
Repository Commit : b731a092-cd38-49dbc-b804-9270f73ec930

Detecting platforms...
Detected following platforms:
  python: 3.8.12

Using intermediate directory '/tmp/8dad4bb5f31e64ce'.

Copying files to the intermediate directory...
Done in 11 sec(s).

Source directory     : /tmp/8da4bbd5f31e64ce
Destination directory: /tmp/build/expressbuild

Python Version: /opt/python/3.8.12/bin/python3.8
Creating directory for command manifest file if it doesnot exist
Removing existing manifest file

Running pip install...
Done in 61 sec(s).
Not a vso image, so not writing build commands
Preparing output...

Copying files to destination directory '/tmp/build/expressbuild'...
Done in 28 sec(s).

Removing existing manifest file
Creating a manifest file...
Manifest file created.

Done in 103 sec(s).
Writing the artifacts to a Zip file
Running post deployment command(s)...

Generating summary of Oryx build
Deployment Log file does not exist in /tmp/oryx-build.log
The logfile at /tmp/oryx-build.log is empty. Unable to fetch the summary of build
Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled).
Deployment successful.
Remote build succeeded!
```

Comment: Can it be the fact that pip has to be upgraded during oryx deployment?
How can I ensure that pip is upgraded during deployment?

Answer (score 0):

As you have not shared your YAML File, here is the recommended sample of Azure Functions Python deployment from the GitHub Repo of [Microsoft-Azure Pipelines - Python Function App - YAML](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/templates/python-functionapp-to-linux-on-azure.yml).

> "Not a vso image, so not writing build commands"

This is the default message that is coming from the [Oryx Remote build](https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/blob/e948e67bb86725825a733a8ab6018bf48b7703f5/src/BuildScriptGenerator/Python/PythonBashBuildSnippet.sh.tpl#L272) where William-MSFT had given the fix for Python pip installation logs not showing.

**Code Snippet from `Oryx BuildScriptGenerator` of Python**:

```
if [ "$ReadImageType" = "vso-focal" ]
then
    echo $ReadImageType
    cat "$COMMAND_MANIFEST_FILE"
else
    echo "Not a vso image, so not writing build commands"
    rm "$COMMAND_MANIFEST_FILE"
```